# Android Java, Speech to text and text to speech - What is a good way to stop the app from listening to itself?

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

I made an app in Andoid Studio with Java, that will listen to speech, recognize it, turn speech to text, and when I allow it to it will respond back with text to speech.

In the beginning I got a lot of self-repeating, because it listened to itself, spoke back, listenede to itself, spoke back, and so on.
So far I have limited this behavior with this code:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
       startlytting();
   }
}, 1000);
```

It still happens somethimes, probably because some response speeches are longer than 1000ms.
Is there a way I could know when the text-to-speech is done speaking, and then turn on the speech listener?

Comment: if you are using [`TextToSpeech`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech) then you can use [`OnUtteranceCompletedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener) or [`UtteranceProgressListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/UtteranceProgressListener)

Comment: Thanks, think I got it working :)